# error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier android was not recognized

Tags: android

1>------ Clean started: Project: PlayTubeTv, Configuration: Release|AnyCPU ------
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(113,5): error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier android was not recognized.
========== Clean: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
Clean failed.

trying to build android app